# Wondering if there is a hotkey/group mechanism to quickly select a subset of bones from an armature

Tags: rigging, bones

I've been learning rigging and animating etc and often find myself repeatedly selecting the same collection of bones, eg the 4 feet control bones and spine root bone for keyframing a walking animation. At the moment I am manually selecting the bones every keyframe,I was wondering if there was a quick way selecting them all with one/two clicks.

I have tried to use Bone Groups as described in the manual but right click -> selecting them in the outliner does not select anything. I added them by selecting bones in pose mode <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for bone group menu -> Assign to New Group, and a bone group dutifully appeared in the outliner.

Let me know if a .blend or screenshots would help illustrate the problem, and thanks for any assistance! (Perhaps it is of note I am running 2.8 under Ubuntu 22.04)

Comment: Hi and welcome :)  [images](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/200919/edit) are always useful, you can upload blend files with [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you select one of the bones and then <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> *> Group*, you'll select the whole bone group.

Comment: Brilliant thanks, that's exactly what I was after